# Where can I get beta versions of the Android Studio Gradle Plugin?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

The [new vector assets](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/09/android-studio-14.html) in Android Studio 1.4 requires the Android Studio Gradle Plugin version 1.4.0-beta3 or later. [This page](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system) says they are up to 1.5.0-beta1.

But when I enable that in my `build.gradle` file I get this error:

```
Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.4.0-beta6.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.4.0-beta6/gradle-1.4.0-beta6.pom
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.4.0-beta6/gradle-1.4.0-beta6.jar
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.4.0-beta6/gradle-1.4.0-beta6.pom
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.4.0-beta6/gradle-1.4.0-beta6.jar
Required by:
    :AndroidBackgroundSync:unspecified
```

Indeed if you check [that URL](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/) it only goes up to 1.3.1.

How can I actually use this thing?

Comment: just setup your build.gradle like this: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.4.0-beta6'`

Comment: Yeah that's what I did that led to this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link for last beta version for Gradle:  [link](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle/view)

For beta versions add `jcenter()` as a repository:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0-beta1'
    }
}
```

By the way you can use stable version like this:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1
```

Comment: Yeah there is no 1.4.0-beta6 at your link. It was the `jcenter()` line that fixed it - thanks!

Comment: Link's still alive, but it appears bintray is no longer being updated because Google don't care

Answer (score 6):

The link in the accepted answer is out-of-date. Currently, the Android Gradle plugin is published to the Google Maven repository (https://maven.google.com), so you can browse it and find the latest version of the package:

```
 com.android.tools.build.gradle
```

The Alpha and Beta versions are listed as well.

UPD: the link to the exact package is: https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#com.android.tools.build:gradle

Comment: do you have a link to release notes of beta versions by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

In your `build.gradle` project file put

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.4.0-beta6'
    }
}
```

then sync project with gradle files or, alternatively, write in the console:

```
./gradlew clean build
```

You can check for the last beta version for Gradle
[here](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle/view)